# How to use Group-Object to extract key info and ConvertTo-HTML

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I have a csv file with various email addresses and collaborators. I then use `| Group-Object INVITER_EMAIL -AsHashTable –AsString` to create a hash table with keys where an INVITER_EMAIL can have multiple collaborators.

I am able to show on screen using:

```
foreach ($User in $Collaborators.keys) {
  $Collaborators[$User] | select INVITER_EMAIL,COLLABORATOR_LOGIN,INVITE_ACCEPTED,ITEM_NAME,URL_TO_ITEM       
}
```

but when I try to pipe `| ConvertTo-HTML` it won't format the string correctly.
I can do `[string]$Collaborators.'user@email.com'` which gives me the correct HTML I want to generate for one user, but having difficulty getting this to go through the foreach loop. Not sure what I may be missing, but I'm hoping to get each of these into a separate $body of a form email at some point. Not sure if this is possible or not? Thx

```
$Collaborators

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                      
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                      
user@email.com           {@{REAL_OWNER_EMAIL_DOMAIN=somewhere; REAL_OWNER_EMAIL=user@email.com; REAL_OWNER_FIRST_NAME=Anna; REAL_OWNER_LAST_NAME=Someone; OWNER_LOGIN=admins@email...
```

Comment: `$Collaborators.Values |ConvertTo-Html`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, unless <tr><td>18</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>System.Object</td><td>False</td></tr> the system.object somehow gets handled in the output?

Comment: Can you edit your question showing as an example of how `$Collaborators` looks like?

Comment: Hmm, this seems to work. foreach ($Col in $File3.keys) {

    [string]$body = $File3[$Col] | select INVITER_EMAIL,COLLABORATOR_LOGIN,INVITE_ACCEPTED,ITEM_NAME,URL_TO_ITEM | ConvertTo-Html

    Send-MailMessage -To "admin@email.com" `
    -from "admin@email.com" `
    -SmtpServer "Smtp.company.com" `
    -Subject $subject `
    -BodyAsHtml -body $body } I had to cut the test file down to 2 test users.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are started correctly in your question.

But the idea is getting information of each person and combining from it a new object and putting it to the array. You just need to create a customObject in each loop cycle.

For Example.

```
foreach ($User in $Collaborators.keys) {
    [array]$MyList += [PSCustomObject]@{
        Email = $Collaborators[$User].Name
        Inviter = $Collaborators[$User].INVITER_EMAIL
        Login = $Collaborators[$User].COLLABORATOR_LOGIN
    }
}
```